# Is there an easy way to close a scratch buffer/preview window?

Tags: buffers, scratch-buffer

One of the plugins I have installed (probably Supertab) provides a nice view of documentation for the currently highlighted item in the completion menu:

[image]

The (apparently) scratch buffer remains open even after I exit the completion (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>). Then, to quit it, I do `<c-w>↑:q`, but I find having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> extremely annoying (one reason why I avoid splits).

What's a quick way to close this scratch buffer? Is there a native way, or do I have to write a mapping?

Comment: Something that might make `Ctrl` less annoying is remapping `Caps Lock` to `Ctrl` or swapping them if you want to keep `Caps Lock` available.

Comment: Which plugin you use for python code complete? For example `jedi-vim` have option `g:jedi#auto_close_doc`.

Comment: @AlexKroll to be honest, I have no idea. I think it might be Supertab. These are the plugins I've installed: https://github.com/murukeshm/vimrc/tree/master/bundle. I don't have Jedi installed.

Comment: @muru `g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose (default 0)`
Looks like it's what you want `:he supertab-closepreviewonpopupclose`

Comment: @AlexKroll Yes, that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Realize the post is old, well if it helps,[found a plugin for it](https://github.com/mtth/scratch.vim)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The top window is called the preview window. So any of `<c-w>z`, `<c-w><c-z>` or `:pc[lose][!]` should work.

The below is the help for `:help :pclose`

```
CTRL-W z        CTRL-W_z
CTRL-W CTRL-Z   CTRL-W_CTRL-Z
:pc :pclose
:pc[lose][!]    Close any "Preview" window currently open.  When the 'hidden'
                option is set, or when the buffer was changed and the [!] is
                used, the buffer becomes hidden (unless there is another
                window editing it).  The command fails if any "Preview" buffer
                cannot be closed.  See also :close.
```

Another relevant help page would be `:help preview-window`

Comment: Yay for `:pc`! I didn't realise that the "preview" name was special.

Answer (score 35):

For my specific case, the preview window was opened by plugins. So, I used plugin configuration to automatically close these windows.

#### Supertab

As suggested by Alex Kroll:

```
let g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose = 1
```

#### YouCompleteMe

```
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
```

If the second variable is set, the first has no effect. From the docs:

```
The *g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion* option

When this option is set to '1', YCM will auto-close the 'preview' window after
the user accepts the offered completion string. If there is no 'preview' window
triggered because there is no 'preview' string in 'completeopt', this option is
irrelevant. See the |g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt| option for more details.

Default: '0'
>
  let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 0
<
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The *g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion* option

When this option is set to '1', YCM will auto-close the 'preview' window after
the user leaves insert mode. This option is irrelevant if
|g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion| is set or if no 'preview'
window is triggered. See the |g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt| option for more
details.

Default: '0'
>
  let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

another nice option, which is relevant also in other cases, is using `:only` to close all other windows, including the preview:

```
:on[ly][!]
:{count}on[ly][!]
CTRL-W o                        *CTRL-W_o* *E445*
CTRL-W CTRL-O                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-O* *:on* *:only*
    Make the current window the only one on the screen. All other
    windows are closed. For {count} see |:quit|.
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option that automatically closes the preview window and that should work with multiple completion plugins was [suggested by deoplete's author in an issue](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim/issues/115#issuecomment-170237485):

```
autocmd InsertLeave,CompleteDone * if pumvisible() == 0 | pclose | endif
```

The downside is that you won't be able to focus the scratch window, so no scrolling. But for quick lookups it's the most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

## Jedi

*if not using with YCM*

```
let g:jedi#auto_close_doc = 0  " close preview window after completion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: [bufutils.vim](https://github.com/smitajit/bufutils.vim)

It closes scratch buffers, location list, error list, etc...