# Accessing references or documentation from within Vim

Tags: help-system

I assume the only documentation that comes with Vim is about Vim.

If I install plugins there will be documentation of the plugins as well.

But is there documentation for other languages in Vim?

An example would be, say I am coding in Python in Vim, and want to quickly look up list comprehensions in Python. It would be great if I can just type `:h python-doc` in Vim and the Python documentation is brought up in Vim documentation.

Other examples would be `:h markdown` to bring up markdown syntax etc.

Is this kind of thing already on the web? Are there such docs which I can download and `:helptags`?

Comment: I don't think this exists, but it could be a *really* cool plugin.

Comment: Well, I don't know of any, and while this would be cool, it would be also a lot of effort to convert existing documentation to vim-help file.

Comment: There are plugins which show the help for the current function while doing autocompletion (like in [my question here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4056/205)), but I don't know of any like you describe.

Comment: Take a look at [ref](https://github.com/thinca/vim-ref).  There are many resources for it out there.  A partial list of said resources has been compiled in the [wiki](https://github.com/thinca/vim-ref/wiki/sources).  You'll need to do some leg work to make full use of it, but you'll never look back.

Comment: Just want to throw out there that `gD` can jump to the definition of a function that is defined in standard libraries if you are writing C code. I think that's kind of related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at either

[vim-plugin-viewdoc](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-viewdoc) to view help inside vim (it supports a lot of sources and can be extended)

or [investigate.vim](https://github.com/keith/investigate.vim) which can be used to look up documentation in your browser.

For python there is also [pydoc.vim](https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim).